# Conflicting types error while passing pointer to the string as argument to function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

[image: Error description]As I wrote in subject, I am getting conflicting types error when I try to pass pointer to the struct, delcared using array of structs. Have you got any suggestions to remove this error? What I am missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 10

void count_length(struct abc *_el);

struct vector {
    double x;
    double y;
};

struct abc {
    struct vector vec;
    double length;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct abc set[N];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        set[i].vec.x = rand();
        set[i].vec.y = rand(); 
        count_length(&set[i]);
    }


}

void count_length(struct abc *_el)
{
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        _el->length = sqrt(pow(_el->vec.x, 2.0) + pow(_el->vec.y, 2.0));
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message and on which line?

Comment: Please post textual information as text, not as picture of text.

Comment: I cannot see the pic. If it's text, do paste text as text, not as bitmap.

Comment: Thanks, although somebody has answered yet, and he managed to solve my problem  so I won't edit it now.

Comment: do not use leading underscores, leading double underscores, and underscore followed by capital letter in names,  Such is 'reserved' for the system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep the function declaration

```
void count_length(struct abc *_el); /* compiler don't knows what is struct abc as you have defined it after this statement */
```

after structure not before. for e.g

```
struct vector {
    double x;
    double y;
};

struct abc {
    struct vector vec;
    double length;
};
void count_length(struct abc *_el); /* here compiler knows what is struct abc */
```